# Найти минимум исключая ноль

Tags: php, max, min

Вопрос больше по логике. Как в php найти минимум из чисел 0, 1, 2, 3, где порядок значимости чисел в порядке увеличения 1, 2, 3, 0?
Есть шкала оценок 1, 2, 3, 0 по нескольким пунктам характеристик, где 1 – это лучший результат, а 0 символизирует отсутствие оценки (самый худший). Из этого ряда нужно найти лучший результат.
Можно, конечно, найти минимум из 1, 2, 3, а потом посмотреть, есть ли ноль среди оценок, но думаю, есть вариант и поизящней. Возможно, объяснил непонятно – лучше покажу на примере:
Показатель 1 - Оценка 1
Показатель 2 - Оценка 3
Показатель 3 - Оценка 0
Показатель 4 - Оценка 2
Показетель 5 - Оценка 1
Здесь наилучший показатель это Оценка 1.

Comment: Заменить ноль на значение заведомо большее максимального. Отсортировать штатно. При необходимости выполнить обратную конвертацию.

Comment: Да, так и сделал.
$res = min(
Показатель1 == 0 ? 4 : Показатель1,
Показатель2 == 0 ? 4 : Показатель2,
Показатель3 == 0 ? 4 : Показатель3
);